# Could we tell that cancerous cells behave that way because-of their genetic machinery is work in a "primitive" way like Amoeba?

Tags: cell-biology, cancer, protozoa

*Amoeba* sp. is unicellular, so can't form a tissue. It need not go through any apoptosis. It just continuously get doubled.

Could we compare them with cancer-cells?

**or in-reverse**,

could we tell that cancer-cells are a sort of mutated cell, that is behaving like *Amoeba*, or behaving in a primitive manner, and **lost its later-upgrades**?

It seemed to me when I came to know that,  mutation in many possible, separate genes, can cause mutation (probably that's why all environmental articles about different mutagens lead to the same disease... cancer). So I was wondering about there could be a common-cause behind all these cancers ... which maybe a loss in all latter-upgrades.

Comment: I don't think cancer cells are free-living. What do you mean by "later upgrades"?

Comment: Evolutionarily acquired characteristics to form a tissue and organ of particular shapes, that is absent in primitive organisms like Amoeba.

Comment: I didn't mean cancer cells if go to nature will behave like amoeba. I'm editing the question title. Thanks for your suggestion